# How much can the hypotheses of the Schwarz integral formula be weakened?

Tags: complex-analysis, hardy-spaces

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_integral_formula, which I will paraphrase here, if $f$ is a holomorphic on the closed unit disk $\{ \lvert z \rvert \leq 1 \}$, then

$f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\lvert \zeta \rvert = 1} \frac{\zeta+z}{\zeta-z}\operatorname{Re}(f(\zeta)) \frac{d\zeta}{\zeta} + i \operatorname{Im}(f(0))$,

for all $\lvert z \rvert < 1$.

My question is this, how much can one weaken the hypothesis that $f$ is holomorphic on $\overline{D}$, while retaining the conclusion?

For instance, if $f$ is only assumed to be holomorphic on the open disk $D$, and continuous on $\overline{D}$, will the conclusion hold? If not, can one add an extra hypothesis, so that the conclusion will hold, and will allow the function to have some kind of singularity at the boundary. The type of singularities I am interested in are branch type singularities, such as fractional powers $(z-1)^a$, say, for some $a>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is holomorphic in the open disk and continuous on the closed disk the formula is valid. All you have to do is to apply the formula for the disk $|z|=1-\epsilon$ and then  let $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Thank you. It is correct, but it does involve interchanging a limit with an integral, which requires some justification. I know I already accepted your answer, but do you mind expanding it a little to explain why the limit of the integral over the circle of radius $r$, for $r<1$, as $r$ approaches $1$ from below, is indeed the integral over the circle of radius $1$? This can be done using the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem for instance, since the integrand is continuous on the annulus $1-\epsilon \leq r \leq 1$, which is compact, so the integrand is bounded.